# How to use StanfordCoreNLP achieve the conversion of Chinese Penn Treebank（s-expression）to CONLL format？

Tags: stanford-nlp

I have Chinese constituency treebank in Penn Treebank (s-expression) format and I want to get the conll format data. I konw the English data can be converted by StanfordCoreNLP using this command

```
java -mx1g edu.stanford.nlp.trees.ud.UniversalDependenciesConverter -treeFile treebank > treebank.conllu
```

And I also know StanfordCoreNLP support choosing Chinese language model by using command

```
java -mx3g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -props StanfordCoreNLP-chinese.properties -file chinese.txt -outputFormat text
```

When I use the command

```
java -mx3g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.trees.ud.UniversalDependenciesConverter -props StanfordCoreNLP-chinese.properties -treeFile chtb_0001.nw > chtb_0001_nw.conllu
```

There is nothing changed, in this case, StanfordCoreNLP tools still choose English Model not Chinese Model. I can't get any more details from the home page of StanfordCoreNLP. so I want to get help from StackoverFlow.

Comment: I know nothing about Stanford-NLP but looking at the source of https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/ud/UniversalDependenciesConverter.java it seems to be hardcoded to English and does not use the props parameter. Perhaps you need to take another look.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work:

```
java -Xmx1g edu.stanford.nlp.trees.international.pennchinese.UniversalChineseGrammaticalStructure -treeFile ctb_example.txt -checkConnected -basic -keepPunct -conllx
```